# Can not set class or style in specific date with primeng calendar

Tags: typescript, calendar, primeng, angular7

I want to add class with specific date in calendar.
So i can add style the color background with different condition.

I am use angular 7 and use primeng for calendar.
How to set default date with different class or color on specific date?

Please see below for sample calendar that i want to build or
any others module angular for build like this?

Thank you

[Sample calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSV2u.png)

Comment: Do u have a solution? if yes can u post code sample